# PyQt5 + Python 3: passing lists, dicts as signal arguments across threads

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, pyqt5, thread-safety, signals-slots

I am using pyqtSignal to send a python list as an argument from worker thread to main thread. When does qt create a copy of the object being passed as argument. According to: http://www.embeddeduse.com/2013/06/29/copied-or-not-copied-arguments-signals-slots/ the qt should make a copy of the object. However, in the example below the main thread can change the contents of the list being sent from another thread.

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, QObject, pyqtSlot, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

class ClassProcessing(QObject):

    py_sig_send_data = pyqtSignal(list)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # initialize some variables
        self.data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    def worker(self):
        print(self.data)
        self.py_sig_send_data.emit(self.data)
        time.sleep(1)
        print("modfied data in thread", self.data)

class ClassProcessingThread(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.objThread = QThread()
        self.objThread_id = 1
        self.objThread_finished = False
        self.processing = ClassProcessing()
        self.processing.moveToThread(self.objThread)
        self.objThread.started.connect(self.processing.worker)
        self.objThread.start()

class SomeClass(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    @pyqtSlot(list)
    def receive_data(self, data):
        print("received data", data)
        data[1] = 42
        print("modified data", data)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    processing_thread = ClassProcessingThread()
    some_class = SomeClass()
    processing_thread.processing.py_sig_send_data.
        connect(some_class.receive_data)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
received data [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
modified data [1, 42, 3, 4, 5]
modified data in thread [1, 42, 3, 4, 5]
```

Can someone please explain to me how to pass a list in a pyqtSignal in a thread-safe manner. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PyQt doesn't behave in the same way as Qt when it comes to passing container types between threads using signals.

Specifically, there is no automatic conversion [1] to the equivalent Qt types, and therefore no implicit copying. PyQt does provide a mechanism to *explicitly* request such conversions, though. To do that, you can define a custom signal using either `QVariantList` or `QVariantMap`:

```
    py_sig_send_data = pyqtSignal('QVariantList')
```

However, it's important to note that `QVariantMap` only supports string keys.

All in all, though, it's probably simpler, clearer and safer to just explictly copy mutable python types before passing them via signals across threads.

[1] Or at least, [not any more](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/incompatibilities.html#pyqt4-v4-7-4).

Comment: Interesting this isn't stated anywhere more explicitly. I have searched extensively but apparently not in the right place. The explicit copy is probably useful for sending the signal once; the data copied to data_buffer and data_buffer passed as argument. What about continuous sending (e.g. 50 times per second)? The sending and the receiving thread could be accessing the data_buffer at the same time.

Comment: @John.  If you want to avoid copying, you'll need to use some kind of [locking mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_%28computer_science%29).